# Heroku API returns 403 in Python only

Tags: python, heroku, python-requests, http-status-code-403

So I am working on a Python script to communicate with the Heroku API to get dyno information, but it doesn't seem to work in Python. However, with the exact same information, it works fine in cURL:

Works (cURL 7.51.0):

```
curl -XGET -H 'Authorization: Bearer <BEARER>' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3' 'https://api.heroku.com/apps/<APP>/dynos/<DYNO>'
```

Fails (Python, both on 2.7.12, 3.5.3, and 3.6.1):

```
import json
import requests
callapi = requests.get('https://api.heroku.com/apps/<APP>/dynos/<DYNO>', headers={"Authorization":"Bearer <BEARER>", "Accept":"application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"})
json = callapi.json()
print(json)
```

...with error:

```
{'id': 'forbidden', 'message': 'You do not have access to the app <APP>.'}
```

Where `<APP>` is my app name, `<DYNO>` is the dyno name, and `<BEARER>` is my bearer token.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So after debugging it seems like the Heroku CLI is trying to override the provided <BEARER> with the one of the Heroku account logged into the CLI. Doing it on another machine remedied the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `requests` uses the `.netrc` file if no `auth` argument is provided: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/?highlight=netrc#netrc-authentication

So `requests` is using your Heroku credentials (`heroku login` saves your credentials in that file).

An easy way to fix the issue is expained here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/?highlight=netrc#new-forms-of-authentication

**TL;DR:** remove the `Authorization` header and use the `auth` parameter with a custom class.

This is the implementation I'm using:

```
class HerokuBearerAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, api_key):
        self.api_key = api_key

    def __call__(self, r):
        r.headers.update({'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(self.api_key)})
        return r

myHeaders = {'Accept': 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3'}
response = requests.get(myUrl, headers=myHeaders, auth=HerokuBearerAuth(api_key))
```